# Changing background color animation not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, click, onload

I am trying to make the background color of the body change every second using the button.
I need the background to change on the click of the button for other reasons (I cannot use a normal interval, timeout, or @keyframes).
I can not figure out what is wrong with my code. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="click_me">Loaded</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" defer>

        const btn = document.getElementById("click_me");
        const body = document.querySelector("body");
        
        btn.onclick = () => {
            if(body.style.backgroundColor == "white"){
                body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            } else if(body.style.backgroundColor == "black"){
                body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }
        }

        setTimeout(()=>{
            btn.click();
        },1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looks like the defautl background color for the body is really "transparent". So when you check for the white value its never found. So you just need too add an OR statment to check for the transparent value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="click_me">Loaded</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" defer>

        const btn = document.getElementById("click_me");
        const body = document.querySelector("body");

        // debug stuff
        console.log(`Here is the default value of your body color:`)
        console.log(body.style.backgroundColor)
        
        btn.onclick = () => {
            if(body.style.backgroundColor == "white" || body.style.backgroundColor == ""){
                body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            } else if(body.style.backgroundColor == "black"){
                body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }
        }

        setTimeout(()=>{
            btn.click();
        },1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you don't want to do this you could just always set the body color to white on load. But you really probably should be using some type of reset [Reset CSS](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). This way you know values like this are the same across all browser instead of finding out later what went wrong. Never know, maybe the default value of the background color could change in the future to something else.

Answer (score 0):

there is a mistake in your code you didn't setted the background color for the body and trying to get it so you are getting empty value every time and you have if conditions on the basis of white and black color so didn't working try this code I had runned this on my local system its working now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: white;">
<button id="click_me">Loaded</button>

<script type="text/javascript" defer>

    const btn = document.getElementById("click_me");
    const body = document.querySelector("body");
    
    btn.onclick = () => {
        console.log(body.style.backgroundColor);
        if(body.style.backgroundColor == "white"){
            body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        } else if(body.style.backgroundColor == "black"){
            body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
    }

    setTimeout(()=>{
        btn.click();
    },1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <button onclick="color();" id="click_me">Loaded</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function color(){
    var body1 = document.getElementById("body");
     if(body1.style.backgroundColor == "white"){
            body1.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        } else if(body1.style.backgroundColor == "black"){
            body1.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
    }
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    var btn = document.getElementById("click_me");
        btn.click();
    },1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Set white as default!